# CentOS 6.5 mysql use alotof memory

Tags: mysql, centos, vagrant, my.cnf

i am trying to set up my VM via vagrant, the VM OS is CentOS 6.5 
when i install mysql 5.6 :
 - MySQL-server-5.6.17-1.el6.x86_64.rpm   
 - MySQL-client-5.6.17-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
 - MySQL-shared-compat-5.6.17-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
 - MySQL-shared-5.6.17-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
 - MySQL-devel-5.6.17-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
and i didn't config anything to my.cnf file, so it is default file, but when i check the memory used, i saw mysql service use alot of memory (>400M):

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                                         
4576 mysql     20   0 1308m 446m 6896 S  0.0 23.8   0:00.27 mysqld
```

how can I reduce the memory which occupied by mysql.

Answer (score 2):

in my.cnf config file in [mysqld] section

add 
performance_schema = off

save and reload mysqld